# How to convert a utf8 literal (ie '\u1F606') to a rune? (NOT GET THE UTF8 FROM THE RUNE!)

Tags: string, go, utf-8, unicode-literals, rune

I'm trying to generate sequential characters using the utf8 hex codes. For example first part, I'm terming "base" code : 259
second part, Im' terming "end" code : 1 (or, 2, or A, or F, etc)

These are coming in as strings.  Once I append the end code and get a complete string (ie: 259E), how can I convert that into the actual utf8 representation (or "character")

I'm not sure where to start.  I know that `string(rune('\u259E')` will give me the representation ( ▞), but I don't know how to get the string into the rune cast as a (single-quoted) utf8 character code.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s1 := "259"
    s2 := "E"
    s3 := "\\u"+s1+s2
    fmt.Println(s3)
    fmt.Println(string(rune('\u259E'))) 
}
```

The desired outcome is that I'm able to return a utf8 character (and potentially surrogate pairs) from generated string representations of the codes.

The overall gist (for example) is that I'd like the string value "272A" to return as : ✪

Comment: \u1F606 is a UTF-32 codepoint not UTF-8.

Comment: It's a surrogate pair as far as I understand it. But again, I'm not overly concerned with supporting "higher-order" encoding at this point.  Please forgive my ignorance on the nuances of utf-8 vs utf-32.

Comment: @bennowak `\u1F606` is not a surrogate pair.  That would look like `\uD83D\uDE06` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the hex value into an int32.

Then cast that value to a `rune` in the `println`.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

func main() {
    s1 := "259"
    s2 := "E"
    s3, err := strconv.ParseInt(s1+s2, 16, 32)
    fmt.Println(string(rune(s3)))
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Comment: You sir @Strom are a gem!  Thanks a ton for getting me there on that.  Might I ask where you dug to find that gold?  Or what was your thought process?  To help a lowly greenhorn like me to peer into the depths of greatness that I might one day fill my cup at the same mead hall?

Comment: Works on "higher order" surrogates too!  Yipee!

Comment: @bennowak The logic was: 1. Concatenation doesn't work(the conversion is done during at compile time(https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions) 2. Convert the number to UTF-8 chars and append them into a string(Ouch, there must be a better way). 3. `rune` is an alias to `int32`(https://blog.golang.org/strings), aha, a rune is just a Unicode codepoint. 4. Now to convert the hex string to a number (https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt). 5. Mix it all together in a large pot, stir, and taste(er... test).  Success.

Comment: @bennowak "Works on "higher order" [codepoints] too! Yipee!": this code will work on all single character codepoints (including Emojis).  Modifications would have to be made to support multi-codepoint glyphs (displayed characters), the longest of which are the flags of England, Scotland, and Wales at seven codepoints, 224 bits!